# JAVA: Different objects with different methods

Tags: java, methods

I want different objects to have different methods

For example how to make following java pseudocode work?

```
Button b[] = new Button[5];
button[0].onClick = new method(arguments){
    Log.i("a", "button0");
    return true;
}
button[1].onClick = new method(arguments){
    Log.i("a", "button1");
    return false;
}


button[1].onClick(123);
```

**UPD1:**
Guys, what about following code I found on the internet. How to make this Button class and write function similar to setOnClickListener? PS: Button is my own class and it is not taken from default libs.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i("a", "Yohoho");
    }
});
```

Comment: What frame work? Javafx/Swing/awt/SWT...?

Comment: Give your Button class a field which is set in a constructor. Then, when the onClick method is called, choose functionality based on that field's value. Then make sure to set this field when you initialize Button objects.

Comment: @MadProgrammer pure JavaSE. Actually I'm developing for Android

Comment: Usually you'd use something like an observer pattern, where you would pass an object which implements a known interface which the button can call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's add some code to what Jon Skeet wrote. Conceptually your `onClick` instance variable should be a reference to something that implements the `ClickHandler` interface. Let's define such a interface based on what you wrote.

```
interface ClickHandler {
    public boolean click(Object[] arguments);
}
```

Now your `Button` class needs a reference to a `ClickHandler`, a method to set one, and a method to call one. A prototypical button would thus look like this:

```
class Button {
    private ClickHandler onClick;
    public void addClickHandler(ClickHandler clickHandler) {
        onClick = clickHandler;
    }
    public boolean click(Object[] arguments) {
        onClick.click(arguments);
    }
}
```

Now `ClickHandler` is a functional interface (in Java 8 terms), so when you have a `Button` instance you can either `addClickHandler` using an anonymous class or a lambda

```
Button b = new Button();

// java 7
b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public boolean click(Object[] argument) {
        Log.i("a", "button0");
        return true;
    }
});

// java 8
b.addClickHandler(args -> {
    Log.i("a", "button0");
    return true;
});
```

This is the idea. But do note that something like this exists virtually everywhere, so take a look at e.g. swing to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that exactly, but you *could* have:

```
button.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
```

where `clickHandler` could actually be a lambda expression implementing some `ClickHandler` interface.

The `Button` class itself would be responsible for calling that handler at the right time though, e.g. you might call `button.click()` and it call the handler for you.